# Running a gem on cron with a specific version of ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

We need a certain gem application run on a cron schedule, so we have a dedicated user set up to run this gem.

We are currently using ruby 1.9.2

```
[jobrunner@test-load] rvm list
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p299 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p374 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Unfortunately I need this user to run on ruby 1.9.3. Changing the default ruby version is not an option because rvm is installed system wide (`/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`) and other users on the system rely on 1.9.2.

If I were in an interactive session, it would be as simple as

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

However, it appears I can't use `rvm use` in a non-interactive session (i.e. in the crontab). (I tried it by sticking that in my `bashrc` file and telling cron to look at my `bashrc` file. I ended up forkbombing myself..)

How do I get my crontab using a specific version of ruby via rvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From tty switch ruby version:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

You should set up cron with rvm:

```
rvm cron setup
```

then your crontab would look like this:

`PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/"

      rvm_env_string='ruby-1.9.3-p194'

      rvm_path='/usr/local/rvm'

      rvm_ruby_string='ruby-1.9.3-p194'

      RUBY_VERSION='ruby-1.9.3-p194'

      GEM_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194'

      GEM_PATH='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global'

      MY_RUBY_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194'

      IRBRC='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc'`

Cron would use 1.9.3 ruby with the above

### EDIT

Just noticed my text was not well formatted on SO, so I have reformatted it

Comment: I really like this answer, but rvm cron setup hangs on the system and locks it for me for some reason. I kept having to kill the session.

Comment: if rvm cron setup hangs just copy what I have provided above removing things that are not in your path, and add to the top of your crontab file, that's the same thing rvm cron setup does

Answer (score 0):

You can source the rvm confined ruby from your script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# load rvm ruby
source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p448@projectX

# ..... rake, ruby, whatever you need your script to do
```

Comment: So this seems like it's creating a wrapper shell script that sources ruby and then calls my script?
Is there any way to run the source statement at the top of the crontab file, sort of how like environment variables can be set at the top? Alternatively, I guess I could just copy the contents of that source file into the crontab, but that seems...dirty.

Comment: rvm generates wrappers already for you, check gem-wrappers gem => https://github.com/rvm/gem-wrappers it is now used in rvm 1.25.0 by default