# rake task is skipping long running shell process

Tags: ruby, rake

I have rake task which runs in every 5 mins with crontab. This rake task has to start one long running background process which creates a file as per task inputs.

For some reason long process is not running . I am using Backticks  to run the command.

Any idea ?

#### rake task file

```
require 'json'

namespace :scrapper do
  path = '/home/ubuntu/users'
  def lockfile
   Rails.root.join('tmp', 'pids', 'leads_task.lock')
  end

  def running!
   `touch #{lockfile}`
  end

  def done!
   `rm #{lockfile}`
  end

  def running?
    File.exists?(lockfile)
  end

 task :get_profile => :environment  do
  unless running?
    running!
    user = User.last
    `/usr/local/bin/casperjs #{path}/scrapper.coffee #{user.id}`
    done!
  end
 end
end
```

cron syntax looks like this

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/ubuntu/UserProfile && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake scrapper:get_profile  --silent >> /home/ubuntu/UserProfile/scrapper_cron.output 2>&1'
```

#### few wried things

1. The cron job is running, i see scrapper_cron.out file get created when i delete it.
2. The rake task is running when i type it in shell and execute it.

Comment: what is in your scrapper_cron.output ? maybe ruby isn't found?

Comment: no. ruby is loading..it is executing it. i confirmed it by putting `puts 'foobar'` .

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar you need to set up crontab with your ruby related environment variables and path, sample is an answer I provided here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649272/running-a-gem-on-cron-with-a-specific-version-of-ruby/20649931#20649931

Comment: maybe something with permissions?

Comment: @bjhaid thanks i will try and confirm it.

Comment: By the way, you could use monit to do stuff like this: http://mmonit.com/monit/   But to get the Rake file working, you should try to reproduce the problem outside of cron.  What user is the cron job running as?  If you log in as that user and run the exact same command, what do you get?

Comment: @IgorKasyanchuk , no..i dont think it is the permission issue. if that will be, it wouldn't even worked it without cron.

Comment: Can you add lots of puts statements so we can know: was the task executed?  Did `running?` return true or false?  Did the script attempt to run your shell command?  What was the return code of the shell command?  (I think you can get that with `$?`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [rake timeout gem](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) in my app which is giving timeout error to the rake task. Since, the cron command includes `silent` flag it is suppressing the error .